# Django website can't find template in new project website

Tags: python, django

Hey I'm looking for some advice on my situation as I can't seem to figure this out.

I'm trying to build a website with Django following along with the tutorial they have on the webpage and I got stuck at a step where I want to add a view to my web page. My folder structure is so fart like this:

```
PersonalWebsite
|
|--PersonalWebsite
          |
          |--urls.py
|--dashboard
      |
      |--urls.py
      |=-views.py
      |--templates
            |--dashboard
                   |
                   |--index.html
```

In my PersonalWebsite/urls.py I have :

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('dashboard.urls')),
path('resume/', include('resume.urls')),
]
```

In my dashboard/urls.py I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

And in my dashboard/view.py I have:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html')
```

Then I have just some html in the index.html.

I'm trying to basically have the dashboard app as the landing page of the website and from there I want to redirect to other apps like portofolio, articles, etc. My issue is that now I get a TemplateNotFound error when the website tries to access dashboard/index.html at localhost:8000/ address. I haven't changed anything in the settings files, it is a standard project.
Any idea's why it can't find the index.html?

Edit:

PersonalWebsite/settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Now that you mentioned this, I think I did not call the install app command and that's missing now so the website doesn't know about it. Is that it?

Comment: Add `dashboard` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` settings

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yep that fixes it. But I have another app also, "resume" which just shows a PDF file and has the same setup as the dashboard except that one is accesible throug localhost:8000/resume. That one works fine without adding it to the INSTALLED_APP list

Comment: Ah but you wouldn't be rendering a template there right? You would be directly sending a file response or similar?

Comment: Ah right! Yea it's a FIleResponse not a template. Weird, why does the installed apps dictate the rendering of a template? I would expect it to just not have access to the app but it seems the app is accessible without putting it in the INSTALLED_APPS, but it's views are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django searches for templates in the following places:

1. Directories specified by the `DIRS` part of the `TEMPLATES` setting.
2. In the `templates` sub-directory of each *installed app* if `APP_DIRS` is set to `True` in the `TEMPLATES` setting.

Considering the above your `TEMPLATES` setting is correct but you haven't *installed* the app `dashboard` so Django will not look for templates in that app, hence you need to install the app by adding it to `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'dashboard' # add it to installed apps
    # Add any other app you may have
]
```